# Using HTML email in Python script to use a for loop to display a python list

Tags: python, html

I have a list made in Python called list_servers which has a list of servers.

I am trying to send an email within the python script that uses HTML to display the list in a readable manner, however, I cannot figure out how to use a for loop in HTML.

I have tried using the Jinja2 module however, I am getting the following error:

**KeyError: '% for item in list %'**

```
html = """\
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>The file attached contains the servers.</p>
{% for item in list %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
""".format(list=list_servers)
```

Can't figure out the error and if there is another way, please let me know!

Comment: I have a small python experience. Yet, are you sure the grammar below is valid within a string? `{% for item in list %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed you confuse two distinct procedures. 
A first way to complete your task is to build the html list before and then insert it within the whole html section:

```
list_servers = ['boo', 'foo', 'bar']
# building the auxiliary string list
items = ["\n    <li>{}</li>".format(s) for s in list_servers]
items = "".join(items)
# insert in the html 
html = """\
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>The file attached contains the servers.</p>{0}
</body>
</html>
""".format(items)
```

The above method used the Python built-in `.format` function. It is valid for simple case as the one in the example. Yet, for more complex HTML construction, you may want to stick with jinja2 functionalities as indicated below:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader
# your template as a string variable
html_template = """\
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>The file attached contains the servers.</p>
{% for server in servers %}
    <li>{{ server }}</li>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
"""
# jinja2 rendering
template = Environment(loader=BaseLoader).from_string(html_template)
template_vars = {"servers": list_servers ,}
html_out = template.render(template_vars)
print(html_out)
```

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thanks so much, I was using jinja2 before but the email showed nothing. Thanks!

Comment: do you know any way to output the list items and any other lists in a table?

Comment: What do you mean by table? A HTML table or an abstract table (array, pandas dataframe, ...)?

Comment: See below as I can't put it here

Comment: I have no knowledge of HTML. Please, look out how to perform such table in HTML and inspire yourself from the code I proposed earlier to build your message.

Answer (score 0):

It worked like a charm. But there is a small catch. If there is a need to use the output for sending mails using SMTP modules then it may not work as MIMETEXT of SMTP will not understand the variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31742484)